# Can you get both records and count of total records in table together from sproc in mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to get some records from the table and count of all the records in the table. I am fetching all the records via select statement and count via @var. My sproc in mysql is as below. When I run it I am getting Error in Query String : Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getallenquiries`(IN `lim` BIGINT, IN `pgid` BIGINT, IN `uid` BIGINT, OUT `totalrec` BIGINT)
NO SQL
BEGIN
SELECT * from admin_enquiry order by enq_createdon desc limit lim offset pgid;
select count(enq_id) into totalrec from admin_enquiry;
END$$
```

DELIMITER ;

I am calling as "CALL  getallenquiries(3,2,1,@totalrec)"
When I run it in phpmyadmin i am able to get both the result sets. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand this correctly, but MySQL already has a function that will paginate (limit) and then another that will return the total count, as if the limit was not applied: SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS

```
mysql> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tbl_name
    -> WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;
mysql> SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

First query returns a limit of 10 results and with the selected fields (* in this case).
The next SQL query returns the size of the results for the previous query if a limit was not applied.

Comment: The issue is more with the behaviour of Sproc with OUT parameter. I took pagination just as an example.
I have used a select * from...  and then select count(enq_id) into totalrec.... 
"totalrec" is my OUT parameter. Which I am not able to get it when I call "CALL  getallenquiries(3,1,0, @totalrec)"

Comment: I think what you are trying to do can not work. Look at this: stackoverflow.com/questions/8307939/how-to-retreive-multiple-rows-from-stored-procedure-in-mysql#answer-8308074

Comment: Ok But I when I try this in in phpmyadmin I am able to run it 
call getallenquiries(3,1,0,@totalrec);
select @totalrec;
But does not work when I call from php